# How can I convert my `winnerCheck` function to work recursively? - C

Tags: c, recursion, iteration, global-variables

**ISSUE:** I'm having a rough time building my understanding of recursion (slow learner), and whenever I'm tasked with creating a `recursive` function, I always create it through `iteration` first.

Then I do my best to hit some of the basic rules of recursion, but usually end up feeling a bit burned out.

All I'm trying to do is convert my `winnerCheck` function to work `recursively`.

Also, I've heard using `global variables` was frowned upon. Is this true? Should I move my array `square` to work locally?

Thanks for any guidance and input you can offer.

**CODE:**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

char square[10] = {'o', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'};

int winnerCheck();

void board();

int main() {

    /*
    char board[3][3] = {
    };

    printf("\t|\t|\t\n");
    printf("\t|\t|\t\n");
    printf("________|_______|________\n");
    printf("\t|\t|\t\n");
    printf("\t|\t|\t\n");
    printf("________|_______|________\n");
    printf("\t|\t|\t\n");
    printf("\t|\t|\t\n");
    printf("\t|\t|\t\n");

*/

    int player = 1, i, choice;
    char mark;
    do {
        board();
        player = player % 2 ? 1 : 2;

        printf("Player %d, enter a number: ", player);
        scanf("%d", &choice);

        //mark = (player == 1) ? 'X' : 'O';

        if (player == 1) {
            mark = 'X';
        } else {
            mark = '0';
        }

        if (choice == 1)
            square[1] = mark;
        else if (choice == 2)
            square[2] = mark;
        else if (choice == 3)
            square[3] = mark;
        else if (choice == 4)
            square[4] = mark;
        else if (choice == 5)
            square[5] = mark;
        else if (choice == 6)
            square[6] = mark;
        else if (choice == 7)
            square[7] = mark;
        else if (choice == 8)
            square[8] = mark;
        else if (choice == 9)
            square[9] = mark;


        i = winnerCheck();
        player++;
    } while (i == -1);
    board();

    if (i == 1)
        printf("==>\aPlayer %d win ", --player);
    else
        printf("==>\aGame draw");
    getch();

    return 0;
}

int winnerCheck() {
    if (square[1] == square[2] && square[2] == square[3])
        return 1;
    else if (square[4] == square[5] && square[5] == square[6])
        return 1;
    else if (square[7] == square[8] && square[8] == square[9])
        return 1;
    else if (square[1] == square[4] && square[4] == square[7])
        return 1;
    else if (square[2] == square[5] && square[5] == square[8])
        return 1;
    else if (square[3] == square[6] && square[6] == square[9])
        return 1;
    else if (square[1] == square[5] && square[5] == square[9])
        return 1;
    else if (square[3] == square[5] && square[5] == square[7])
        return 1;
    else if (square[1] != '1' && square[2] != '2' && square[3] != '3' && square[4]
                                                                         != '4' && square[5] != '5' &&
             square[6] != '6' && square[7] != '7' && square[8]
                                                     != '8' && square[9] != '9')
        return 0;
    else
        return -1;

}

void board() {
    printf("\n\n\tTic Tac Toe\n\n");
    printf("Player 1 (X) - Player 2 (O)\n\n\n");

//prints the board after every input

    printf("    |     |    \n");
    printf("  %c |  %c  |  %c  \n", square[1], square[2],square[3]);
    printf("____|_____|____\n");
    printf("    |     |    \n");
    printf("  %c |  %c  |  %c  \n", square[4], square[5],square[6]);
    printf("____|_____|____\n");
    printf("    |     |    \n");
    printf("  %c |  %c  |  %c  \n", square[7], square[8],square[9]);
    printf("    |     |    \n");
}
```

Comment: Why do you want it recursive? I don't see any particular reason to do this recursive.

Comment: This isn't really a good problem to try to solve recursively. Recursion is mostly used for nested structures. For example, if you're searching for a file, you might call a function to scan a directory for it. If that function sees a directory inside of it, the function would call itself to check that directory, too. For a flat array, you're almost always going to use iteration; a recursive approach usually doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Broman Unfortunately its an assignment requirement... I didn't think it made much sense either.

Comment: You first have to come up with an algorithm for the recursion.  I think you are trying to find three squares in a straight line that all have the same value.  So, 1) Check for value of current square, 2) then check recurisvely for value of all adjacent squares, 3) then check value of next adjacent square in the same direction as step 2.  Have you looked at doing it that way?

Comment: @contrapants I completely agree, but this is an assignment requirement, so I have to make sure recursion fits into that function.

Comment: @JohnMurray I have, but I also have to handle diagonal situations, so I don't know how I can go about this. Perhaps I should create a function for diagonal and straight lines? Not sure.

Comment: Yes.  you will need to create a function that will return the adjacent square for a given direction. `int GetIndexOfAdjacentSquare(int startSquare, int direction), where direction is an enum or a mapped list (e.g. 0 = North, 1 = NorthEast, 2 = East, etc.).  You could then call that function for all possible directions.  The function will return the index in that direction, or a 0 index if heading in that direction would take you off the board.  So, your function will figure out what the diagnol square would be from a given location.  Just one way of doing it.  Recursion would pass direction.

Comment: @user7823016 If it is an assignment, then please cite the complete requirements. It is extremely common here when people ask for help with homework that someone posts a nice answer and then OP says "oh, but we are not allowed to use X"

Comment: @Broman that's just it, the function is not to be hard-coded... like it is now. It just needs to work recursively.

Comment: Recursion is rarely the best solution to a problem. The first thing you have to understand about recursion, is that every time the function calls itself, it will re-instantiate a whole new set of parameters and local variables for the new call. Not only this is expensive, it takes up space in the call stack, that has a fixed, limited size, meaning you can only recurse so many times before your application crashes from stack overflow, that names this website. You should not use recursion lightly, it's a concept that exists and therefore you should know how it works, but it's very rarely useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `winnerCheck` function tests if any of the possible winning conditions is met. And this consists on checking if certain triples are all filed by the same player.

You could hardcode an array with all the triples that guarantee a win. Then checking for a win implies traversing that array, and that can easily be done recursively.

**EDIT**

So there's 8 possible "wining positions" triples, which you could declare for instance as,

```
const int numwinpos = 8;

const int winpos[8][3] = {{1,2,3},
                          {4,5,6},
                          {7,8,9},
                          {1,4,7},
                          {2,5,8},
                          {3,6,9},
                          {1,5,9},
                          {3,5,7}};
```

Regarding the recursive checking procedure here is an example for how to check whether any element of a vector `v` of size `n` satisfies a property `p`.

```
// returns -1 if no v[i] satisfies p
// returns  i if v[i] satisfies p (picks largest i)
// (i>=0) and (i<n)

int recTest(const int v[], const int n){

  if( (n>0) && (!p(v[n-1])) )
    return recTest(v,n-1);
  else
    return n-1;
}
```

**EDIT2:**

So the `winnersCheck` can be of the form,

```
int winnerCheck(char square[], int winseq[][3], int n){
  // there's n winning sequences to test, 0 .. n-1
  // let's check sequence n-1
  int pos0 = winseq[n-1][0];
  int pos1 = winseq[n-1][1];
  int pos2 = winseq[n-1][2];
  if( (n>0) && !(squares in positions pos1, pos2 and pos2 marked by same player) )

    // game does not contain winning sequence n-1
    // so test the other n-1 positions, i.e. 0 .. n-2 
    return winnerCheck(square,winseq,n-1);  
  else
    // either n = 0 and there's no more positions to test 
    // or game contains winning sequence n-1 
    return n-1;
}
```

Of course the condition you need to fill in may be a bit to large to inline in that if. You may want to organise that differently or define so auxiliary function to do that work.

Also here's some modifications to your main code that show how some of the things you had done could be clearer.

```
int main() {

  // Game Board: there's 9 squares in the game
  // 0 1 2
  // 3 4 5
  // 6 7 8

  // ' ' represents "nothing" in a square
  char square[9]={' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '}; 

  // There are 8 possible ways of winning the game
  int nwinseq = 8;
  int winseq[8][3] = {{0,1,2},
                      {3,4,5},
                      {6,7,8},
                      {0,3,6},
                      {1,4,7},
                      {2,5,8},
                      {0,4,8},
                      {2,4,6}};

   // there's player 1 and player 2
   // player 1 goes first  
   int player = 1;   

   // current play
   // at most 9 plays in a game
   int i = 1;

   // winning sequence
   // 8 possibilities (0 to 7)
   // no winning sequence found when game starts
   int w = -1;

   // execute game until it's over
   bool gameOver = false;

   while(!gameOver){    
    // print board  
    board(square);

    // ask player for his move of choice
    int choice; 
    printf("Player %d, enter a number: ", player);
    scanf("%d", &choice);

    // change the square according to player's move
    move(player, square, choice);

    // check for win
    w = winnerCheck(square, winseq, nwinseq);

    gameOver = (w >= 0) // found winning sequence i
            || (i == 9); // or made 9 plays already

    // update play number and player
    // obs: maybe update it only if game is not over
    // matter of taste
    i++;

    if (player == 1)
      player = 2;
    else // player == 2 
      player = 1;
  }

  // Game is over 
  // Print the end result 
  // ...
}
```

and,

```
void move(int player, char square[], int choice){
   if (player == 1)
    square[choice] = 'X';
  else
    square[choice] = 'O';
}
```

Comment: Would you be able to show an example? Because if I hard-code arrays I'm not sure how to run through more than 1 recursively, properly.

Comment: I was mistaken, I'm not sure what to pass to the recTest function, and what satisfies 'property' p. Would you be able to explain a bit more? Having trouble connecting the dots.

Comment: @user7823016 Sure. So, that piece of code `recTest` is meant as an example on the use of recursion to check if any element in an array `v` of dimension `n` satisfies a property `p`.  You want to check if in any of the possible "winning configurations" in the array `winpos`, matches the current state of your game. Of course you need to adapt the code, in particular should pass the game state as an argument too. But the overall recursion scheme is the same.

Comment: I truly hate to be a pain, but I don't know how to fit these pieces together properly. I'm a freshman, and I'm doing my best to learn... but this seems a bit more complicated than I was anticipating. Do you see a clear way to integrate your solution into my (terrible) code? Also, I absolutely appreciate all the help you've provided thus far.

Comment: Edited the code with an addapted `winnerCheck`. It's almost done now, you should finish yourself though. See also some modifications to your code that may help you organise things better.

Comment: Thank you Jorge, I wish I could upvote you more. Thank you, truly.

Comment: as much fun as I've been having trying to fill the last piece of the puzzle in... I'm not getting anywhere, and the assignment is far past-due. I've tried a myriad of possibilities... you said it should be "squares in positions pos1, pos2 and pos2 marked by same player", but aren't the values for nothing also being compared? (It crashes when I try... ` if( (n>0) && !(square[pos0] == square[pos1] == square[pos2]))` which compares the direct values of each of the 3 positions before it goes through to another recursive call... I'm a first year. and I'm having a heck of a time. I'm sorry Jorge

Comment: OK so firstly this `square[pos0] == square[pos1] == square[pos2]` doesn't work. Rather you want to write `square[pos0] == square[pos1] && square[pos1] == square[pos2]`. Secondly indeed this alone isn't enough because you must also check that they are marked with a player move, and not equally empty.

Comment: I had tried `square[pos0] == square[pos1] && square[pos1] == square[pos2]` but since that doesn't work, I thought I was just heading in the wrong direction... How can I check for marked contents and not equally empty? How do I go about comparing something like that with variables square, winseq, and n already being used to mark and compare square[] based on positions?

Comment: Nevermind Jorge, seems they weren't accepting the recursion you were helping me with, since the win-conditions were coded in that one array.

Comment: Sorry to hear about that. It does depend on their goal with the problem. Regarding the previous question, guess it doesn't matter now, but you'd just have to add a condition to check that it's marked, e.g.,  `(square[pos0] == 'X' ||  square[pos0] == 'O') && square[pos0] == square[pos1] && square[pos1] == square[pos2]`